# When stealing from cars, should I check the visor?

Tags: the-long-dark

It took me a long while to discover you could flip sun visors down (duuh) but I never find anything there

Is there ever anything there?

Comment: This question would be way cooler if it were asked in the Freelancing stack exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading numerous Steam community threads, it seems that some people claim to have found items behind visors. If so, these are *extremely* rare and this possibility may have been removed altogether after an update.

---

On 17th August 2018 in ["Milton Mailbag"](http://www.hinterlandforums.com/forums/topic/20994-milton-mailbag-dispatch-8/), Raphael van Lierop of Hinterland provided the following answer to a player's question:

> > People are asking a lot more important questions than me... but I always wondered, what is the point of being able to search the visors in the cars? They never have anything in them. In my first hours with the game I would check them every time.
>
> The idea was that sometimes you would find Notes or Keys under them. We may still do that.

This suggests that, up to this date, nothing is to be found there.

Answer (score 4):

In 2014, Hinterland answered this [post regarding the use of hoods and visors](https://steamcommunity.com/app/305620/discussions/0/619573787368113113/), by saying that both were planned for future use.

[Starting in 2016](https://steamcommunity.com/app/305620/discussions/0/405691491124319236/), a few Steam players indeed claimed having found various items (such as chocolate bars, matches or even cartridges) behind sun visors, but most report having found nothing, not even in years of play. Some among the lucky ones specified playing in lower difficulties, implying the overall more abundant loot is a game-changer regarding sun visors.

So yes, it seems that items can be found in the sun visors, but it's fairly recent and really doesn't happen quite often. The best answer would of course be Hinterland's but since aforementioned post they've kept quiet about it, as to preserve the "mystery" surrounding the question and savor the thought of all these desparate survivors hopefully clinging to the sun visors.